# Incrementing variable in xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a for each loop and a if condition under for loop. I want to increment the value of variable i everytime if the if condition is true. Based on value of variable i I want to implement some logic. Below is the code

```
<xsl:variable name="i" select="0"/>
<xsl:for-each select="Request/ModifyProductsAndPackages/NrcList/Nrc">
<xsl:variable name="typeIdNrcVar" select="TypeIdNrc"/>

<xsl:if test="count(/Request/WaiveNrcList/WaiveNrc/TypeIdNrc[text()=$typeIdNrcVar])=0">
   <xsl:variable name="i" select="$i + 1"/>
   <xsl:if test ="$i=1">
    do something
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each/>
```

Here the value of i could not be incremented. can anyone please suggest as how should i accomplish above task. Thanks for help.

Below is xml structure

```
<Request>
<ModifyProductsAndPackages>
<NrcList>
   <Nrc>
     <TypeIdNrc>14046</TypeIdNrc>
     <ServiceInternalId>98602440</ServiceInternalId>
     <ServiceInternalIdResets>0</ServiceInternalIdResets>
     <ViewableOnly>1</ViewableOnly>
   </Nrc>
   <Nrc>
     <TypeIdNrc>12002</TypeIdNrc>
     <ServiceInternalId>98602440</ServiceInternalId>
     <ServiceInternalIdResets>0</ServiceInternalIdResets>
     <ViewableOnly>1</ViewableOnly>
   </Nrc>
   <Nrc>
     <TypeIdNrc>13006</TypeIdNrc>
     <ServiceInternalId>98602440</ServiceInternalId>
     <ServiceInternalIdResets>0</ServiceInternalIdResets>
     <ViewableOnly>1</ViewableOnly>
   </Nrc>
   <Nrc>
     <TypeIdNrc>14098</TypeIdNrc>
     <ServiceInternalId>98602440</ServiceInternalId>
     <ServiceInternalIdResets>0</ServiceInternalIdResets>
     <ViewableOnly>1</ViewableOnly>
   </Nrc>
 </NrcList>     
 </ModifyProductsAndPackages>
<WaiveNrcList>
<WaiveNrc>
  <TypeIdNrc>12002</TypeIdNrc>
  <ServiceInternalId>98602440</ServiceInternalId>
  <ServiceInternalIdResets>0</ServiceInternalIdResets>
</WaiveNrc>
<WaiveNrc>
  <TypeIdNrc>13256</TypeIdNrc>
  <ServiceInternalId>98602440</ServiceInternalId>
  <ServiceInternalIdResets>0</ServiceInternalIdResets>
</WaiveNrc>
<WaiveNrc>
  <TypeIdNrc>14046</TypeIdNrc>
  <ServiceInternalId>98602440</ServiceInternalId>
  <ServiceInternalIdResets>0</ServiceInternalIdResets>
</WaiveNrc>
</WaiveNrcList>
</Request>
```

The end result I want to achieve is NrcList = NrcList-WaiveNrcList. I want to exclude on the matching records on the basis of TypeIdNrc, ServiceInternalId, ServiceInternalIdResets
Below is the result xml

```
<Request>
  <NrcList>
    <Nrc>
      <TypeIdNrc>13006</TypeIdNrc>
      <ServiceInternalId>98602440</ServiceInternalId>
      <ServiceInternalIdResets>0</ServiceInternalIdResets>
<ViewableOnly>1</ViewableOnly>
</Nrc>
<Nrc>
<TypeIdNrc>14098</TypeIdNrc>
<ServiceInternalId>98602440</ServiceInternalId>
<ServiceInternalIdResets>0</ServiceInternalIdResets>
<ViewableOnly>1</ViewableOnly>
    </Nrc>
</NrcList>
</Request>
```

Another approach:

Comment: You need to use recursive templates for this. Please describe in more detail exactly what you want to achieve. What variable do you want to increment? How do you plan to leave the loop (when all elements are done? when `$i` is a certain value? what does $i mean?)

Comment: I want to increment variable i and if value of i is 1 then I want to implement some logic else do something else logic

Comment: In XSLT, variables cannot be modified. Why don't you edit your question and explain in more detail **what** are you trying to accomplish - not **how** are you hoping to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that copies only the `Nrc` elements that do **not** have a matching record in `WaiveNrcList`- based on matching `TypeIdNrc`:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="waive" match="WaiveNrc" use="TypeIdNrc" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <Request>
        <NrcList>
            <xsl:for-each select="Request/ModifyProductsAndPackages/NrcList/Nrc[not(key('waive', TypeIdNrc))]">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </NrcList>
    </Request>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Request>
   <NrcList>
      <Nrc>
         <TypeIdNrc>13006</TypeIdNrc>
         <ServiceInternalId>98602440</ServiceInternalId>
         <ServiceInternalIdResets>0</ServiceInternalIdResets>
         <ViewableOnly>1</ViewableOnly>
      </Nrc>
      <Nrc>
         <TypeIdNrc>14098</TypeIdNrc>
         <ServiceInternalId>98602440</ServiceInternalId>
         <ServiceInternalIdResets>0</ServiceInternalIdResets>
         <ViewableOnly>1</ViewableOnly>
      </Nrc>
   </NrcList>
</Request>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael for your reply. In this case the key is TypeIdNrc,ServiceInternalId and ServiceInternalIdResets. Is there a  way to match on all the 3 fields.

Comment: @user3366906 Yes, use a concatenation of all three - both in the key definition (the `use` attribute) and when calling the key() function.

Comment: ` <NrcList1>
    <xsl:for-each select="Request/ModifyProductsAndPackages/NrcList/Nrc[not(key('waive', concat(TypeIdNrc,ServiceInternalId,ServiceInternalIdResets)))]">
     <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
   </NrcList1>`

Comment: <xsl:key name="waive" match="WaiveNrc" use="concat(TypeIdNrc,ServiceInternalId,ServiceInternalIdResets)"/> Is that right?

Comment: @user3366906 Yes, except that in order to prevent false positives, you should place a delimiter between the values, e.g. `concat(TypeIdNrc, '|', ServiceInternalId, '|', ServiceInternalIdResets)`.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I found another way of doing this. Do you see any advantage of doing this without key as mentioned above

Comment: @user3366906 Hard to say without knowing what that "another way" is. But speaking in general, using a key is the most efficient way, and IMHO it also makes for a clear and easy-to-maintain code.

Comment: <xsl:if test="count(/Request/WaiveNrcList/WaiveNrc/TypeIdNrc[text()=$typeIdNrcVar]/../ServiceInternalId[text()=$ServiceInternalId]/../ServiceInternalIdResets[text()=$ServiceInternalIdResets])=0">

Comment: Sorry. Above is the if condition I was referring to instead of if condition with key. Thanks.

Comment: @user3366906 If I am reading this correctly (very difficult!), it will work - but less efficiently than a key. It certainly has no advantage over a key.

Comment: Thanks for answering all the questions.